# Saving a new variable to a .jld (or hdf5) file while preserving contents

Tags: file-io, julia, hdf5

Is there a cleverer way to add a variable to a `.jld` file than to read it all in and then rewrite with an extra variable? I think that this is possible using hdf5 but I could find if it was implemented in the JLD package yet.

This is the way I am doing it at the moment.

```
using JLD
if isfile(filename)
    a = load(filename) #load all vars
    jldopen(filename, "w") do file
        for (k,v) in a #rewrite original vars
            write(file, k, v)
        end
        write(file, "additional_variable", add_var) #write new var
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should open the file with mode `r+` instead of `w`

```
jldopen(filename, "r+") do file
    write(file, "additional_variable", add_var)
end
```

Comment: yep got it cheers, I had tried "rw" but not that... bit slow today. Did I miss it in the docs or is it just a given?